# Trouble creating terse and generic error type

Tags: generics, types, error-handling, rust

I'm having a hard time trying to create an error type which is both generic and doesn't devolve into a mess of `impl`s and generic arguments.

I have a struct with a few generic parameters for subsystems, each of which has methods returning custom error types:

```
struct App<A: ..., B: ..., ...> {
    a: A,
    b: B,
    ...
}

impl<A: ..., B: ..., ...> App<A, B, ...> {
    fn do_something_cross_cutting(&self) -> Result<(), AppError> {
        a.run()?;
        b.run()?;

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

How should `AppError` be cleanly defined? At first I tried using `quick_error!` like so:

```
quick_error! {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    enum AppError<A: ..., B: ..., ...> {
        AError(err: A::Error) {
            from()
            display(...)
        }

        BError(err: B::Error) {
            from()
            display(...)
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

But `quick_error!` doesn't seem to support generic enums. Furthermore, since `AppError` is now generic *and* it doesn't look like it's possible to define type aliases inside `impl` blocks, every method that could fail would have a very extensive return type (`Result<_, AppError<A, B, ...>>`).

`quick_error!` could be avoided, but again at the expense of readability and code size, and it doesn't solve the second problem.

I came up with the following alternative, but isn't compiling:

```
quick_error! {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    enum AppError {
        AError(err: Box<Error>) {
            display(...)
        }

        BError(err: Box<Error>) {
            display(...)
        }

        ...
    }
}

impl<A: ...> From<A::Error> for AppError {
    fn from(err: A::Error) -> Self {
        AppError::AError(Box::new(err))
    }
}

...
```

`rustc` complains with `` the type parameter `A` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates ``, and I have no idea how to fix it.

The last possibility is the least verbose: simply propagate a `Box<Error>`. It's my plan B. The biggest problem is that useful information is lost. By defining `AppError` (and, recursively, subsystem-specific error types), I get a poor man's backtrace on error. Using `Box<Error>` would make errors difficult to trace.

Is there any other alternative, or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: Regarding your backtracing issue: have you tried [`error_chain`](https://crates.io/crates/error-chain)? It has a backtrace functionality, integrated.

Comment: I'll take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with a custom error type which retrieves a backtrace on construction (using the [`backtrace`](https://crates.io/crates/backtrace) crate) and stores the actual error as a `Box<Error>`:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct AppError {
    err:   Box<Error + Send + Sync>,
    trace: Vec<String>,
}

impl AppError {
    pub fn new<E: Into<Box<Error + Send + Sync>>>(err: E) -> Self {
        let mut trace = Vec::new();
        // Get backtrace

        AppError {
            err: err.into(),
            trace,
        }
    }
}

impl Display for AppError {...}

impl Error for AppError {...}
```

The only wrinkle is since `AppError` implements `Error`, I can't have a blanket `impl<E: Error> From<E> for AppError`. Instead:

```
impl<E: AppErrorTag> From<E> for AppError {...}

trait AppErrorTag: Into<Box<Error + Send + Sync>> {}
```

And then `impl AppErrorTag for x {}` for every relevant error type `x`.

With this, error types are terse (simply `AppError`), generic (just a matter of tagging relevant types), and has a backtrace. The disadvantage is that the error can't be deconstructed and inspected. The need for a tag can be a bit of a pain specially for errors on external crates due to coherence rules. The real ideal solution would use negative trait bounds, but we're not there yet.

Answer (score 2):

What does the error `` the type parameter `A` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates `` mean? Let's look at a reduced example:

```
trait Foo {
    type Error;
}

struct Bar;

struct Baz;

impl Foo for Bar {
    type Error = std::io::Error;
}

impl Foo for Baz {
    type Error = std::io::Error;
}

struct Quux;

impl<T: Foo> From<T::Error> for Quux {
    fn from(err: T::Error) -> Quux {
        Quux
    }
}
```

The issue is that a type `U` can match `T::Error` for multiple `T`. Here, for example, `std::io::Error` would match both `Bar::Error` and `Baz::Error`. So, which type should the compiler choose for `T`?

The solution is simple: don't use `A::Error` and `B::Error`; instead, define `A` and `B` to *be* the error types directly. When you use `AppError` within `App`, you'll return `AppError<A::Error, B::Error>` instead of `AppError<A, B>`. Yes, you'll have to repeat `::Error` everywhere; I don't think there's a solution for that.